# Connection to crossbar.io either hangs or disconnects

Tags: python, wamp, twisted, autobahn, crossbar

I'm trying to connect to crossbar on a remote host using Python with autobahn[Twisted]

I'm using a modified example code from PubSub:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os import environ
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner

class Component(ApplicationSession):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
       ApplicationSession.__init__(self, config)
        print("component created")

   def onConnect(self):
        print("transport connected")
        self.join(self.config.realm)

    def onChallenge(self, challenge):
        print("authentication challenge received")

    @inlineCallbacks
    def onJoin(self, details=None):
        print("session attached")
        self.received = 0
        for x in range(1, 501):
            sub = yield self.subscribe(self.on_event, u'com.myapp.topic{}'.format(x))
            if x % 100 == 0:
                print("Subscribed to {} topics".format(x))

    def on_event(self, i=None):
        print("Got event: {}".format(i))
        self.received += 1
        self.config.extra for configuration, etc. (see [A])
        if self.received > self.config.extra['max_events']:
            print("Received enough events; disconnecting.")
            self.leave()

    def onDisconnect(self):
        print("disconnected")
        if reactor.running:
            reactor.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = ApplicationRunner(
        url=u"ws://localhost:8080/ws",
        realm=u"realm1",
        extra=dict(
            max_events=5000,  # [A] pass in additional configuration
        ),
    )
    print(runner.log)
    runner.run(Component)
```

I have an instance of crossbar running on my localhost for testing, and when I access that, everything works.

```
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 component created
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 transport connected
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 session attached
(stuff happens here, events get published, until max is reached)
2016-04-01T17:26:19+0000 Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2016-04-01T17:26:19+0000 disconnected
2016-04-01T17:26:19+0000 Main loop terminated.
```

But if I try to connect to other hosts, two things will happen:
If it's a secure port:

```
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 component created
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 transport connected
```

(the session never gets attached, program hangs)

If it's an insecure port:

```
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 component created
2016-04-01T17:26:16+0000 transport connected
2016-04-01T17:26:19+0000 disconnected
2016-04-01T17:26:19+0000 Main loop terminated.
```

(the connection kicks me out automatically before the session gets attached

The host I'm trying to connect to has 8080 for secure port and 8081 for insecure. So all I change is:

```
url=u'ws://{hostname}:8080/ws', (or)
url=u'ws://{hostname}:8081/ws',
```

I wanna know if I'm missing something obvious about WAMP connections or if this is probably a configuration issue on the crossbar instance I'm trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by running this on a virtualenv with the following versions of autobahn and twisted:

```
autobahn==0.10.2
Twisted==15.1.0
```

I don't know why the latest versions were behaving this way, I just know that my code above will only work on those versions.